# C programme memory violation

Tags: c, gcc, turbo-c++

I have below programme where memory is read-only, but I am still able to write to it.

```
main()
{
char *p="amit";
p[0]="s";
printf("%s",p);
}
```

The output is "smit"

Is it the expected output since `p` points a location that is read-only? When I run this programme on GCC or on Visual C++, I get a segmentation fault, but on Turbo C++ I get "smit".

Please confirm this behaviour...

Comment: I have re-tagged your question, it's not quite C++ related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing to a string literal gives undefined behavior, so the compiler is allowed to do anything it wants when you do that.

The simple answer is that Turbo C++ compiles for real-mode, so none of the memory is protected. Neither the compiler nor the OS will stop you from writing anything anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry for ur response but @Jerry in a programme where i perform memory operations frequenty will not give me a troule and @Jerry are u aware of this behaviour before...

Comment: @AMIT: Writing to string literals with that compiler will just silently change its value. Yes, at least as I recall, I was aware of this years ago (but it's been long enough that it's hard to say for sure...)

Comment: do you mind helping to edit the C tag wiki, in particular the FAQ on the tag wiki page? When you see the same incarnation of the same question asked before, it becomes useful for those working on merging questions.

Comment: @Tim Post: I'll take a look when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3):

Undefined behavior is undefined behavior: whatever you get, you can't complain.

String litterals used to be in writable memory.  Older compilers have this behavior.  Some compilers (at least older versions of gcc, it seems to have been removed in the 4.X version) have an option to get it.  I recommand not using it excepted to help porting old applications depending on it.

Comment: +1. The most annoying thing about undefined behavior is that it sometimes just works, leading to complacency. I would much prefer if it _always_ delevired a mild electrical shock to the author :-)

Answer (score 1):

The memory used by the string `"amit"` does not *have* to be read-only. Indeed, this is compiler-dependent and therefore you're seeing this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that you declared a pointer on the stack but it isn't clear where "amit" is supposed to be stored.  You want the string on the stack too and the easiest way to do that is to allocate the storage for it by changing p from a pointer to a character array.

Change your code to this:

```
main()
{
  char p[] = "amit";
  p[0]='s';
  printf("%s",p);
}
```

Comment: I think there is absolutely no difference between `char *p` and `char p[]`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Cygnus, you _are_ wrong. In more ways than you can possibly imagine :-)

Comment: If that is so, can you explain me the difference?

Comment: @Cygnus there is definate difference between these two

Comment: @Cygnus, yes, and it's impossible to tell you those ways in this limited space.

Comment: @Meagar thanks for ur response but ur option is already known

Comment: Your comments are not really helpful, you know? Thanks for nothing :(

Comment: @CygnusX1 *p will only allocate the size of a pointer on the stack.  Where will "amit" be stored?  p[] will cause "amit\0" to be stored on the stack.  There is no difference in the usage of the two but there is a difference during compile-time memory allocation.

Comment: @Cyg, here's some helpful advice for you: re-read the chapter of the book that deals with pointers, especially char pointers. And dry your tears.

Comment: @bmenrigh: Somewhere else. It seems it will be stored in program code (did some testing myself). Thanks for clarification!

Comment: @CygnusX1 You're right, I checked with gdb and indeed, *p does point to "amit".  The trouble is that "amit" is in the .text section along with the machine code.  The compiler marked that section as readable and executable but not writable.

Comment: Actually it went into .rodata but that is in the same 4k memory page as .text and a few other sections.

Answer (score 1):

That the memory in the run-time machine is read-only is completely irrelevant. Before trying to write indirect into memory (which I assume is read/write) through p, you must first define that memory. Of course if the run-time memory is indeed read-only, well, it ain't gonna work no matter how many compile errors you fix.

So you might have:`main()
{
  char amit[20] = "amit";
  char *p = amit;         // which is the same as &amit[0]`

// yes, you are permitted to write into amit[] like these next two lines:
  p[0]="s";
  p[1] = '\0';  // you must terminate the string if you don't want to use strcpy( ) or its friends

// but it's better in every way to strcpy( ) into amit[], like this:
  strcpy( amit, "s" );

printf("%s",p);
}

Answer (score 0):

The memory used for "amit" is not only readable and this is compiler dependent weather we can rewrite on the location p[0] or not .I have observe same in (GCC) 4.1.2 also .Yes its expected output and its an undefined behaviour ...